# Get path from Uri

Tags: java, android, file, uri, storage-access-framework

I am making the User selects a Storage either Internal or External Storage(SD Card) using the Storage Access Framework Document.

After the user selects the Directory I want to check if the Directory selected by the user is of the Root folder of the particular Storage( Internal or External Storage).

This is how I am trying to achieve this and this is what I have achieved till now-

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 42) {
            Uri treeUri = data.getData();
          if (!wrong_directory_selected(treeUri, Context)) {
               // Permission granted for the Directory as required by me

                } else {
                    // Permission not granted for the Directory as required by me
                }
            } 
        }
    }

public boolean wrong_directory_selected(Uri uri, Context con)
    {
        final File uri_path=new File(FileUtil.getFullPathFromTreeUri(uri,con.getApplicationContext()));
        if(uri_path!=null)
        {
            if(uri_path.getName().toLowerCase().equals(new File(PathForWhichPermissionNeeded).getName().toLowerCase()))
            {

                return false;
            }
        }

        return  true;
    }
```

And this is my `FileUtil` class-

```
public final class FileUtil {


    private static final String PRIMARY_VOLUME_NAME = "primary";




    @Nullable
    public static String getFullPathFromTreeUri(@Nullable final Uri treeUri, Context con)
    {

        if (treeUri == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        String volumePath = getVolumePath(getVolumeIdFromTreeUri(treeUri),con);

        if (volumePath == null)
        {
            return File.separator;
        }
        if (volumePath.endsWith(File.separator))
        {
            volumePath = volumePath.substring(0, volumePath.length() - 1);

        }

        String documentPath = getDocumentPathFromTreeUri(treeUri);
        Log.e("DocumentPath",documentPath);
        if (documentPath.endsWith(File.separator))
        {
            documentPath = documentPath.substring(0, documentPath.length() - 1);

        }

        if (documentPath.length() > 0)
        {
            if (documentPath.startsWith(File.separator))
            {

                return volumePath + documentPath;
            }
            else {

                return volumePath + File.separator + documentPath;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            return volumePath;
        }
    }


    private static String getVolumePath(final String volumeId, Context con)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            StorageManager mStorageManager =
                    (StorageManager) con.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

            Class<?> storageVolumeClazz = Class.forName("android.os.storage.StorageVolume");

            Method getVolumeList = mStorageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumeList");
            Method getUuid = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getUuid");
            Method getPath = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getPath");
            Method isPrimary = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("isPrimary");
            Object result = getVolumeList.invoke(mStorageManager);

            final int length = Array.getLength(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                Object storageVolumeElement = Array.get(result, i);
                String uuid = (String) getUuid.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
                Boolean primary = (Boolean) isPrimary.invoke(storageVolumeElement);

                // primary volume?
                if (primary && PRIMARY_VOLUME_NAME.equals(volumeId))
                {
                    return (String) getPath.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
                }

                // other volumes?
                if (uuid != null)
                {
                    if (uuid.equals(volumeId))
                    {
                        return (String) getPath.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
                    }
                }
            }

            // not found.
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private static String getVolumeIdFromTreeUri(final Uri treeUri)
    {
        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri);
        final String[] split = docId.split(":");

        if (split.length > 0)
        {
            return split[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private static String getDocumentPathFromTreeUri(final Uri treeUri)
    {
        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri);
        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
        if ((split.length >= 2) && (split[1] != null))
        {
            return split[1];
        }
        else
        {
            return File.separator;
        }
    }


}
```

So basically `onActivityResult` I am checking if the `treeuri` of the selected directory path is equal or not to the path required by me.

This is the `treeuri` for the selected directory `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3A`

This is the path which is being returned from the above `treeuri` `/storage/sdcard0`

The path which is expected to be returned is `/storage/sdcard1`.

So even after choosing the right directory the wrong path is being returned.

Can anyone help me to find the exact path of the `treeuri` or Can anyone help me to check if the `treeuri` belongs to Internal Storage or External Storage (SD Card).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to check if the Directory selected by the user is of the Root folder of the particular Storage( Internal or External Storage).

You are welcome to use `getParentFile()` on `DocumentFile`, and see what it returns for the top of the document tree. They do not document exactly what happens here, but it should either return `null` or throw some sort of exception. You could then use that to determine whether the returned document tree happens to be a root of something.

However, there is no requirement that the "something" be [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) or [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). The user could choose a document tree from Google Drive, or a Windows file server, or any number of other data sources. There is no requirement that you be able to identify where the data source comes from.

> And this is my FileUtil class

Much of the code in that class makes invalid assumptions. The rest uses reflection, and it is quite possible that [the next version of Android will ban access to hidden APIs using reflection](https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/01/18/think-hard-about-hide.html).

> Can anyone help me to find the exact path of the treeuri

There is no "exact path of the treeuri".

> Can anyone help me to check if the treeuri belongs to Internal Storage or External Storage (SD Card)

That is not possible in general.

Comment: Your answers are always excellent with a proper expatiation for every action. But in my case I simply cannot accept any `Uri` and leave it as it is. I need this `Uri` to access the Directory using Storage Access Framework. If the user selects the wrong path and I don't inform him then he will think that the app is not functioning properly and not handling the files the way it should where as there would be a problem with the permission. Is the any nearest work around which can be used by me?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602: "But in my case I simply cannot accept any Uri and leave it as it is" -- you do not have a choice with the Storage Access Framework. "If the user selects the wrong path" -- that's a fundamental problem in your app's design. **There should not be a wrong path**. Your app should be useful no matter what the user chooses from the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` `Intent`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to check if the Directory selected by the user is of the Root folder of the particular Storage

That is very simple. If the content scheme ends on `%3A` than it is.

So check `data.getData().toString()` for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I know if the `treeuri` is of Internal Or External Storage.

Comment: Also will the `%3A` method be constant through various devices?

Comment: Tree uries are never for internal storage. Only for external and removable.  Those for external contain ''/primary%3A".

Comment: What if the user chooses the Internal Storage ( where DCIM, Download and other folders are stored)?

Comment: As said: internal storage cannot be chosen. The DCIM and Download folders and so are on external storage. On the path indicated by `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Look at the function name ;-).

Comment: Have you checked all the things i said? Please report.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through all the info given by you. By Internal I mean that the Storage which is mentioned under the name "Internal" in the Storage Access Framework(Storage in which all the folder such as DCIM, DOwnload are present) and by External I mean the removable Storage such as SD Card, removable Pendrive which is attached through an OTG cable etc. So I want to check if the directory is of the root folder of which storage Internal or External. For checking whether the root directory is selected or not has been solved by you using the `%3A` method and is not an issue now.

Comment: Can you please help.

Comment: This File Manager https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.filemanager works fine(with the device with which I am having the issue) in identifying if the right directory is chosen or not.